# Regex that will match PHP variable but not object and function invocation

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a regex that will match one of

```
$foo $bar $baz
```

but not

```
$foo->bar
```

So far, I have

```
/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*(?!->))/
```

Unfortunately, this pattern matches `$fo`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT0qC9/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a possessive quantifier that will disallow backtracking into the `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` subpattern:

```
\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*+(?!->))
                        ^^
```

or even (as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` = `\w` if you are not using `/u` modifier or `(*UCP)` verb):

```
\$([a-zA-Z_]\w*(?!->))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tA0dE1/1)

The issue is that when the negative lookahead fails backtracking gets into play, and as `*` allows backtracking into the quantified subpattern, the `o` that is not followed with `->` is found and a match is returned.

See [how your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/tA0dE1/2), pay special attention at the backtracking steps:

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter: If there is anything unclear,  please feel free to drop a comment.